# Populate jQuery function variables with JSON array data

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

UPDATE to show working script. Hope this helps someone. :)

```
//Parse JSON array into javascript array  - REQUIRED FOR dynamic add
 const tooltime = JSON.parse(toolitems);
  console.log(tooltime);  
  
  //Log items on stop
  const draggableOptions = {
   stop: function(evt, ui){
      logItems()
   }
}
  //end log

     //DYNAMICALLY generate new copies of items
  $("#menu .menu-item").click(function () {
    // find associated item in toolitems.items array
    const tool = tooltime.items.find((o) => o.id === this.id)
    const $div = $("<div>")
    .data('type', this.id)
    .draggable(draggableOptions)
      .css({
        id: "draggable",
        padding: "0.5em",
        float: "left",
        margin: "0 10px 10px 0",
        cursor: "move",
        position: "absolute",
        background: "rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.5)",
        border: "1px solid #ccc"
      })
      .addClass("draggable", "ui-widget-content")
      .append(
        '<div id="block_container"><div class="remove_block"></div><img src="https://assets.codepen.io/759025/' +
          tool.imagefile +
          '" alt="' +
          tool.item +
          '"></div>'
      )
      .css({
        width: 100
      })
      .append('<div>' +
          tool.item +
          '</div>')
    .css({
      "text-align": "center",
      "font-size": "24px",
      padding: " 0.25em",
      "line-height": "100%"
      //"white-space": "nowrap"
    })
      .appendTo("#containment-wrapper")
      .draggable({
        containment: "#containment-wrapper",
        stack: ".draggable",
        scroll: false
      })
      .resizable({
        minHeight: 100,
        minWidth: tool.imagewidth,
        maxHeight: 500,
        maxWidth: 500,
        aspectRatio: false
      })
  });
```

I have a jQuery function that is dynamically generating draggable items on menu click.  Currently - in building my app, I have written out an identical function for each type of draggable item - which all work fine. I am looking to combine these into just one function and populate the item attributes from a JSON array. Any assistance is much appreciated - thanks!

Array:

```
var toolitems =
  '{ "items" : [' +
  '{ "id":"firewall" ,"item":"Firewall" , "category":"Network Devices" , "imagefile":"firewall1.svg", "imagewidth":"100" },' +
  '{ "id":"datadiode" ,"item":"Data diode" , "category":"Network Devices" , "imagefile":"datadiode.svg", "imagewidth":"100" },' +
  '{ "id":"router" ,"item":"Router" , "category":"Network Devices" , "imagefile":"router.svg", "imagewidth":"200" },' +
  '{ "id":"switch" ,"item":"Switch" , "category":"Network Devices" , "imagefile":"server.svg", "imagewidth":"200" },' +
    '{ "id":"Server" ,"item":"Server" , "category":"Servers" , "imagefile":"Server", "imagewidth":"200" },' +
  
  '{ "id":"networkL0" ,"item":"L0" , "category":"Network Levels" , "imagefile":"L0.svg", "imagewidth":"200" },' +
  '{ "id":"thecloud" ,"item":"The Cloud" , "category":"Other" , "imagefile":"thecloud.svg", "imagewidth":"100" ]}';
```

The places I need to add the variables are commented:

Function:

```
$(function () {

//VARIABLE "id" is example #firewall

  $("#firewall").click(function () {
    var dynamic_div = $(document.createElement("div"))
      .css({
        id: "draggable",
        padding: "0.5em",
        float: "left",
        margin: "0 10px 10px 0",
        cursor: "move",
        position: "absolute",
        background: "rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.5)",
        border: "1px solid #ccc"
      })
      .addClass("draggable", "ui-widget-content");

    $(dynamic_div)
      .append(

//VARIABLE "imagefile" is img srg, VARIABLE "item" is alt

        '<div id="block_container"><div class="remove_block"></div><img src="firewall1.svg" alt="Firewall"></div>'
      )
      .css({
        width: 100
      });

//VARIABLE "item" is example "Firewall"

    $(dynamic_div).append("Firewall").css({
      "text-align": "center",
      "font-size": "24px",
      padding: " 0.25em",
      "line-height": "100%"
    });


    $(dynamic_div)
      .appendTo("#containment-wrapper")
      .draggable({
        containment: "#containment-wrapper",
        stack: ".draggable",
        scroll: false
      })

//VARIABLE "imagewidth" is minWidth

      .resizable({
        minHeight: 100,
        minWidth: 100,
        maxHeight: 500,
        maxWidth: 500,
        aspectRatio: false
      });
  });

//END  
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I helped you yesterday with this UI, this is an extension of my suggestions.

First match the id of the menu items to the id in your `toolitems` then you can use Array#find() to get the object needed to create your new element. I simplified this only getting some text.

I also used a global `draggableOptions` object that you can pass to the new element draggable method. The `stop` event uses the suggestions I provided yesterday of how to loop over all the items to create an array of objects.

The following is not well styled and the items are very primitive but the dragging works as does the logging of array of items meta data that you can store

```js
const draggableOptions = {
   stop: function(evt, ui){
      logItems()
   }
}

$('#menu .product-add').click(function(){
   // find associated item in toolitems.items array
   const tool = toolitems.items.find(o=> o.id===this.id)
   // only getting text for now. You can extend this for image, category etc
   const $div = $('<div>').data('type', this.id)
                          .text(tool.item)
                          .draggable(draggableOptions);
                          
   $('#containment-wrapper').append($div)             

})

function logItems() {
  const dataArr = $('#containment-wrapper').children().map(function () {
      const $el = $(this);
      const obj = {
        type: $el.data('type'), // from data attribute,
        left: $el.css('left'),
        top: $el.css('top'),
        zIndex: $el.css('zIndex'),
      };
      return obj;
    }).get();
  console.log(dataArr);
}
```

```css
#containment-wrapper {
  margin-left: 200px;
  height: 90vh;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  background-position: 50% 25%;
  background-size:80%;
}

#outsidecontainer {
  border: 2px solid gray;  
}

#menucontainer {
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.remove_block{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  cursor: default;
}

div.remove_block:after{
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\00d7"; /* This will render the 'X' */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<div id="outsidecontainer">
  <div id="menucontainer">
     <h4>Products</h4>
    <ul id="menu">
     
      <li>
        <div class="product-add" id="router">Router</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="product-add" id="firewall">Firewall</div>
      </li>
     
    </ul>
   
  </div>
  <div id="containment-wrapper">
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <script>var toolitems =
  { "items" : [
  { "id":"firewall" ,"item":"Firewall" , "category":"Network Devices" , "imagefile":"firewall1.svg", "imagewidth":"100" },
  { "id":"datadiode" ,"item":"Data diode" , "category":"Network Devices" , "imagefile":"datadiode.svg", "imagewidth":"100" },
  { "id":"router" ,"item":"Router" , "category":"Network Devices" , "imagefile":"router.svg", "imagewidth":"200" },
  { "id":"switch" ,"item":"Switch" , "category":"Network Devices" , "imagefile":"server.svg", "imagewidth":"200" },
  { "id":"Server" ,"item":"Server" , "category":"Servers" , "imagefile":"Server", "imagewidth":"200" },  
  { "id":"networkL0" ,"item":"L0" , "category":"Network Levels" , "imagefile":"L0.svg", "imagewidth":"200" },
  { "id":"thecloud" ,"item":"The Cloud" , "category":"Other" , "imagefile":"thecloud.svg", "imagewidth":"100" }]};</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I see how it is working to pull from the array.

Comment: Is is more straightforward for me to grab the info straight from the JSON data, or should I parse it to a javascript array first?

Comment: You have to parse it to javascript in order to iterate and for elements to be objects. Note that manually creating JSON the way you did is not very useful and hard to work with

Comment: Yes- thanks... I will eventually be retrieving the JSON data from a database, but need all the client side functionality first.  Trying to future proof it just a little. :)

Comment: In my answer if you pasted everything after `toolitems =` into a json file and fetched it from server it would parse normally. Or paste it into a JSON validator and it will pass

Comment: I am a little confused on how to complete the remaining conversion of my original properties.  In your example you switched to const $div from my dynamic_div variable as well as gave the object data "type".  I am not sure how to append the right properties such that it matches correctly.

Comment: I created that `type` concept in the previous answer. You need a way to to the reverse lookup from the stored data to create the proper display when page loads. My `logItems()` array data may need some refinement but using that `type` would allow you to look up what is needed in `toolitems` for image, text etc

Comment: Your updates in question are flawed. You get one tool object using the element id. Then you use `tool.PropertName` for the properties in that tool object. An element has no `this.item` or `this.category` , those properties only exist in each tool object. Look at how I set the `text()` using `tool.item`

Comment: Ah - okay - that makes more sense.  I did not realize I did not have to declare everything and could use the ID as the reference and it would work.  Thank you.